# Not proper field show for forms in yii2

Tags: php, forms, yii2

I'm creating a simple form by Yii2 but instead of form field page, I only get the codes I added into view part.
the code for controller part:

```
namespace backend\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use backend\models\PostForm;
use Yii;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex(){

        return $this->render('index');
    }
    public function actionNew()
    {
        $model = new PostForm;
        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate())
        {
            return $this->render('_show', ['model'=>$model]);
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->render('_form', ['model'=>$model]);
        }
    }
}
```

the codes for model part:

```
namespace backend\models;

use yii\base\Model;

/**
* 
*/
class PostForm extends Model
{
    public $title;
    public $content;
    public $date_added;

    public function rules()
    {   
        return [
            [['title','content','date_added'],'requiered'],
            ['date_added','integer']

        ];

    }

}
```

and the codes for view part is:

```
<?php

use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<? $form->field($model, 'title'); ?>
<? $form->field($model, 'content'); ?>
<? $form->field($model, 'date_added'); ?>

<? Html::submitButton('register'); ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

but this is the output I get:
[output photo](http://uupload.ir/files/64u7_screenshot_from_2016-04-04_21-29-58.png)

and this is the status of files and folders in sublime environment

[trace of files and folders:](http://uupload.ir/files/81d6_screenshot_from_2016-04-04_21-31-43.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing  =  in  `<?=`

```
    <?php

          use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
          use yii\helpers\Html;
    ?>

          <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

          <?= $form->field($model, 'title'); ?>
          <?= $form->field($model, 'content'); ?>
          <?= $form->field($model, 'date_added'); ?>

          <? Html::submitButton('register'); ?>
  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

You have also a wrong value in rules : required and not requiered 
try with the correct  value

```
 [['title','content','date_added'],'required'],
```

Comment: Thanks for ur attention, but this is the error I got after doing that : 
 PHP User Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class requiered does not exist' .
and there is stack trace too.

Comment: I have slightly update the answer .. but this error came from _form or from  _show ..and the code you showed is for which of these two ,,, . please eventuallly show the code for both..

Comment: Weel check for the error related to the rules please and give a feedback

Comment: yeah the reason for the second error was that typo. sorry for that.
Thanks.

Comment: do not worry, there's nothing to apologize ..in case you can also mark the answer as useful